# FileMaker Script - How to perform a find and omit certain records

Tags: filemaker

Here's the script I have currently:

[image]

To test I created four work order records in the date range I'm using.  In this script I'm telling it to omit one of the work orders from the find, but it still says "4" for the value of gNumRequestOpened.

Am I misunderstanding how to script a find?  Is there a better way to do a find an omit records with certain criteria?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Omit Multiple Records`](http://www.filemaker.com/help/html/scripts_ref1.36.80.html) step is meant to be used outside of a find request to omit a certain number of records beginning with the current record. It's not meant to be used within a find request.

You need to use [`Omit Record`](http://www.filemaker.com/help/html/scripts_ref1.36.79.html). Replace your `Omit Multiple Records` step with the following:

```
New Record/Request
Set Field[WorkOrder::_pk_WorkOrder; "42594"]
Omit Record
```

Comment: Thanks, I also found that"contrain found set" also works (but it has to be called AFTER "perform find".